# WSO2 IS minimum client ID length

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 IS 6.0. Is there a minimum client ID length required to set a client ID in OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration? If there is any default length, how do I change it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no defined minimum length for client ID.
When you are [creating the application through REST API](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.0.0/apis/application-rest-api/#/Applications/createApplication) you can define the client ID (even if you input a single character as the client id, it will be considered). So, if the application developer/admin defines the client id be mindful to add an unguessable id.

If the client id is empty, a random id will be generated by the server. Refer to the [code base](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/217aa8a9c768302fba3b30161d305354df61202c/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth/OAuthAdminServiceImpl.java#L274). That generated client ID has a length of 28 characters. There is no config to change the default length for the generated client id.